# Image not aligned consistently between IE, FireFox, and Safari

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a search button following an input field, specified like this:

```
<div class="sidebarsection">
    <input id="queryfield" placeholder="Search previews..."> 
    <button class="search-button" onclick="runSearch()"><img  src="images/search.png" /></button>
</div>
```

The associated CSS is

```
#queryfield {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
}

.search-button {
    width: 26px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.search-button img {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

In FireFox, this looks correct, like this:

[image: FireFox]

In IE, this looks wrong: the image is offset near the top:

[image: IE]

In Safari on the iPad, this is also wrong:

[image: Safari]

In Chrome, it's also not right:

[image]

Is there a way to make all browsers display the image as FireFox does in the above examples?

Comment: One thing that might help is adding 5px of margin or padding to your img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used to this way remove `img tag` and apply in `background image` in your `button` **as like this**

```
<button class="search-button" onclick="runSearch()"></button>
```

**Css**

```
.search-button{
background:url('../images/search.png') no-repeat center cetner;
width: 26px;
height:26px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the `vertical-align` rule is quite buggy and should probably be avoided if you want full control of the look in multiple browsers: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align

Why not use positioning to get what you want or resize your inner image to be the exact height and width of what you want your button to be.